# Smart Error BIOHD-8 on boot

Tags: windows-7, boot, smart

When booting my computer running Windows 7, I get a "Hard Drive Failure" error.

I did a diagnosis and it said " Error code: BIOHD-8" and it said there was a SMART error. The only stuff I could find was for when the computer is already booted up.

Comment: A quick Google search found several hits, all relating to HP computers, and that the message indicates that the hard drive is failing.

Comment: Does your computer still boot normally after the error message, or does it just sit at the error message?

Comment: And is your computer from HP (Hewlett-Packard)?

Answer (score 2):

Searching around a bit on the internet, it seems the error code BIOHD-8 you are seeing is an error code that HP computers display when the hard disk is reporting problems (modern hard disks can tell the computer if they do not "feel well", and [SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) is the mechanism a hard disk uses to report problems to the computer.

It is not clear whether the hard disk is really faulty, or whether the error is a false alarm. At any rate, it is unwise to ignore the error.

You should:

1. Make sure that the backups of your system are working and up-to-date (you *do* have backups, don't you?)
2. Take your computer to a repair shop and have it checked out - it may need a new hard disk. You can do this yourself, but it requires some computer knowledge, so only do it yourself if you feel comfortable with it.

Comment: Don't worry I will ask my Friend to help me, he is an expert on computers and umm... yeah I might want to get the computer checked out too cuz this bad boy was made 2009 with Vista and I replace it with  the hard drive I have now

Comment: Sadly no.... I NEED BACKUPS!!!